# :focus:active together not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want outline should not come on "a" tag on click. it should only come when focus is on link by Tabbing on by jQuery focus event.

Now outline comes on focus and doesnt go out till we not click anywhere else.

Here's my code:

```css
.b {
  color: red;
}
.b:active {
  color: green;
  outline: none!important;
}
.b:focus {
  color: blue;
  outline: 5 px solid red;
}
.b:focus:activer {
  color: green;
  outline: none!important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">testing</a>
<input class="b" type="text"></input>
<input class="b" type="text"></input>
```

Comment: My code as below
.b {
  color: red;
}

.b:active {
  color: green;
    outline: none !important;
}

.b:focus {
  color: blue;
  outline: 5px solid red;
}

.b:focus:activer{
  color: green;
  outline: none !important;
}

<a href="#">testing</a>
<input class="b" type="text"></input>
<input class="b" type="text"></input>

Comment: There's no such thing as `</input>`. `<input>` elements are self-closing.

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS for `a:active`. Note that in your code you have a typo, `:activer`.

```css
.b {
  color: red;
}
.b:active {
  color: green;
  outline: none!important;
}
.b:focus {
  color: blue;
  outline: 5 px solid red;
}
.b:focus:active {
  color: green;
  outline: none!important;
}
a:active {
  outline: none!important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">testing</a>
<input class="b" type="text"></input>
<input class="b" type="text"></input>
```